# RichTextEditor: Any Image RESIZE workaround for Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, image-resizing, rich-text-editor

I got this rich text from Mr. Kevin. See here: http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/demo.htm... This is meant to be cross-Browsing friendly. However, in Google Chrome, You can add an image, but it will NOT resize... There is NO Re-sizable handles. I spent like, now over 3hours trying to work the issue around but it all seems to be getting more rambunctious as i continue.

This is the function used for commands:

```
function rteCommand(rte, command, option) {
    //function to perform command
    try {
        var oRTE = document.getElementById(rte);
        if (oRTE.contentWindow) {
            oRTE.contentWindow.focus();
            oRTE.contentWindow.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
        } else {
            oRTE.document.focus();
            oRTE.document.execCommand(command, false, option);
        }
        loopCnt = 0;

        return false;
    } catch (e) {
        if (debugMode) alert(e);
        //Keep looping until able to set.
        if (loopCnt < maxLoops) {
            setTimeout("rteCommand('" + rte + "', '" + command + "', '" + option + "');", 100);
            loopCnt += 1;
        } else {
            alert("Error executing command.");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any work around for Google Chrome to resize images added inside a rich text editor?

Any idea is highly appreciated

Comment: I believe there is no way to force the browser to put a resize grip on an image; you'll have to code one yourself.

Comment: @Sheng Slogar  The required codes are in that function... just for the records: the adding of the image is executed in this line:: `document.execCommand(command, false, option);` ... this works Perfectly in Firefox [I did NOT Force Firefox to work perfectly]. Why wouldn't it work in Chrome?... You can test the link provided to see for yourself. thx

Comment: Sorry! I'm partially disabled because I'm working on a tiny phone which is driving me nuts. Appending an image to a contenteditable div causes a grip to show in IE (and evidently Firefox) but Chrome dosen't show these grips. They don't have to -- they're another browser. Adding an image dosen't mean everyone has have to have the same bells and whistles. :)

Comment: @ShengSlogar... What do you mean by: _They don't have to -- they're another browser_ ? ofcourse like any other BROWSERS__ there must be away to make My Client STOP_Complaining when their Clients Access their Website in Google Chrome... I can NOT sell your Explanation to my Clients... If you have a **constructive** suggestion, I would highly appreciate other than : _They don't have to -- they're another browser_ .. thx

Comment: I'm just saying that some browsers have extra features and others don't. You can customize every aspect of your webpage by coding your own stuff. Just like Chrome allows CSS scrollbars and in Firefox you must program your own with JavaScript.

Comment: @ShengSlogar Great, would you know of a different approach for chrome other than using the `document.execCommand(command, false, option);` to execute Rich Text Commands?... cz current codes are all aiming at the `exeCommand`.

Comment: Hey, any update on this ?